# Can I create an abstract document listened by the CSS engine?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

It is possibile to create an abstract copy of my document tree that is also listened by the CSS engine?

What do I mean by "listened by CSS engine?" Simply, when I add an id, class, or attribute, to an element of this abstract document, the CSS selector must change the property values of the element like in the real DOM, and I must be able to access those values by using the `getComputedStyle` method

ex. [CSS]

```css
a {
    color: red;
}

.bar {
    color: blue;
}
```

ex. [DOM]

```html
<a href="#">Lorem</html>
```

ex. [JavaScript]

```js
var copiedDocument = document.copy();
var abstractLink = copiedDocument.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];

/* RETURN => red */
getComputedStyle(abstractLink).getPropertyValue("color");

abstractLink.setAttribute("class", "bar");

/* MUST RETURN => blue */
getComputedStyle(abstractLink).getPropertyValue("color");
```

Comment: Why don't you just put it in the DOM, but hide it with `display: none;`? Except for size-related properties, all the CSS property queries should work.

Comment: @Barmar, i want to know property values of elements in different situations, without interfering with the real elements properties.

Comment: @Oriol, document.copy is only an example, it must be an ABSTRACT COPY of the real document.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with it, but maybe the Shadow DOM would be useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Firefox, you can just use

```
var copiedDocument = document.cloneNode(true);
```

However, on Chrome `getComputedStyle` only works for elements in the current document tree.

So you can use something like

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);

var doc = iframe.contentDocument;
doc.replaceChild(document.documentElement.cloneNode(true), doc.documentElement);

var abstractLink = doc.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
getComputedStyle(abstractLink).getPropertyValue("color"); // "rgb(255, 0, 0)"
abstractLink.className = "bar";
getComputedStyle(abstractLink).getPropertyValue("color"); // "rgb(0, 0, 255)"

document.body.removeChild(iframe);
```